# Which udev rule triggered?

Tags: linux, udev

a. Is it possible to find out, which udev rule triggered as soon as some USB/serial device plug-in or plug-out ?

b. Is it possible to reload one specific rule out of many rules, without device replug ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found solution to (a) atleast.

I need to run `udevadm test <sys_path_of_Device>`

This command will run in dry-mode, but will give the correct pointer to rules file.

Answer (score 3):

Run

```
udevadm monitor
```

And all udev information will be displayed on your screen as it is generated.

Comment: It didn't name the udev rule file